# How to define Sagemaker Estimator with entry_point and source_dir once you have your own python package( having setup.py in your root)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

My code structure is like this:

```
|-my_directory
|----- README.md
|----- setup.py
|----- src
|---------- my_train_script.py
|---------- __init__.py
|----- requirements.txt
```

I want to define sagemaker estimator for training step. If I pass "my_directory" as source_dir and
"src/my_train_script.py" as entry_point, I get error saying No module named src/my_train_script
The code work fine if we move my_train_script.py under to root and entry_point=my_train_script.py or we remove setup.py from my directory.
This is not the optimal solution, I want to keep the setup.py for other purposes, is there a right way to define the estimator ?

Example of estimator (Tensorflow)

```
TensorFlow(
    entry_point="src/my_train_script.py",         
    source_dir="my_directory", 

    role=get_execution_role(),
    instance_count=1, 
    instance_type="ml.m5.2xlarge",
    framework_version="2.10.1",
    py_version="py39",
    debugger_hook_config=None,
    disable_profiler=True,
    base_job_name="base_job_name",  
)
```

I want to define sagemaker estimator for training step. If I pass "my_directory" as source_dir and
"src/my_train_script.py" as entry_point, I get error saying No module named src/my_train_script
The code work fine if we move my_train_script.py under to root and entry_point=my_train_script.py or we remove setup.py from my directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) says:

> **`entry_point`** (str or PipelineVariable) –
>
> The absolute or relative path to the local Python source file that
> should be executed as the entry point to training. (Default: None). **If
> source_dir is specified, then entry_point must point to a file located
> at the root of source_dir**. If ‘git_config’ is provided, ‘entry_point’
> should be a relative location to the Python source file in the Git
> repo.

What is the problem with keeping the setup.py file at root level together with the training script?

---

You can try rethinking the structure of your folder in this way:

```
|-my_directory
|----- README.md
|----- my_train_script.py
|----- utils
|---------- setup.py
|---------- __init__.py
|----- requirements.txt
```

and of course inside *my_train_script.py* you can call setup with

```py
from utils import setup
```

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, 
Thanks for your answer. However, we are using setup.py to package our code base that we can import our local modules and so on. For e.g, when you create a venv after that we run = python setup.py develop , and it will install all your dependencies and package your code base.  Which means setup.py is not used by model (such as my_train_script.py)

Comment: Then if the setup file is not used by the training script, you can set the source_dir directly as 'my_directory/src' and entry_point 'my_train_script.py'.

Comment: Not really, because having setup.py, the estimator will interpret our directory as python package and then wouldn't find my entry_point. it should be specificied as src.my_train_script regarding to this discussion https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit/issues/54 .
however I set entry_point="src.my_train_script" the estimator raises an error ( src.my_train_script File not found under directory ...

Comment: At this point i think you need to rethink the folder structure or architecture of your sagemaker solution in general. It is good to follow the guidelines for these aspects, that is, as i indicated in the answer.

Comment: Yes Giusepee, that is what we have working as now ( as mentioned in the question) so moving setup.py out of the root, the solution works fine. Just was wondering in case we keep our folder structure as is, how will be the way we have to define our entry_point ..
Nevertheless, I really appreciate your time to post your answer Thank you so much :)